# Does the term 'molest' exclude actual penetration?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

> Assault or abuse (a person, especially a woman or child) sexually.

It's Lexico's definition. From the definition, it's not entirely clear whether it covers cases of rape or not. Does it? Is raping a special case of molesting or a whole another action?

Comment: If you're asking a question about the language of the law, the answer depends on the jurisdiction; if you're asking a question about the vernacular use of the term, the answer depends on the context.

Comment: The term for sexually and violently penetrating a person against their will is *rape*.

Comment: This is a legal question.  Are you looking for a legal answer or is there a specific example of use that you want to ask about.

Comment: Sergey, answer user105719's question. 'Molest' can mean to push, touch or attack someone in an unwanted way, sexual or otherwise. You might be molested by mosquitoes if you camp near a swamp. Some legal jurisdictions have a specific term 'molestation' for sexual assaults; they can range from touching all the way to penetration.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey If I sought a legal answer, I wouldn't post the question here

Comment: I suspect that the best answer you are going to get will be based on the dictionary meanings of 'molest', e.g. (Cambridge Dictionary) "to touch or attack someone in a sexual way against their wishes", and "to touch, push, etc. someone violently", Rape, being forceful, would seem to partake of both these meanings. There is no doubt in my mind that penetration is definitely not excluded from the meaning of 'molest', in the same way that 'killing' is not excluded from the meaning of 'attack'. Legal language is precise in the way that your question seems to require; ordinary language not so much.

Comment: *wouldn't've posted

Comment: This is like: murder. Does that including shooting or stabbing? geesus.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted so much, OP was asking for clarity on a definition they found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is already pointed out in the comments from @Michael:

> The best answer you are going to get will be based on the dictionary meanings of 'molest', e.g. (Cambridge Dictionary) "to touch or attack someone in a sexual way against their wishes", and "to touch, push, etc. someone violently"

From this, we can infer that rape is a type of molestation, but not all molestation is rape.

Comment: That rape is a _subset_ of molestation?

Comment: Yep exactly @Michael